# How to create a custom "autocomplete" asp.net mvc, (like google)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm just hoping to get an idea on how to go about creating the following functionality on a screen. I've been using webforms in the past so I felt the need to get over it and start using MVC before I get left behid, so to speak.. thus the project is in Asp.NET MVC, (& JQUERY, but have been getting more comfortable with it lately), so I feel it should be do-able at this point)

[image: idea]

I basically want an autocomplete. The employee no textbox should act as input, and as the user types, the items below should render/be visible & update, something to that effect. I'm id like to colour code them by relevancy/or by time.

I think I've got the following problems/questions.

1.) How would I submit without a button click.

and my controller would return a JSON result (I'm assuming would be the best route)

2.) Update/Render my results without redrawing/posting the page

3.) Applying the colours (but its minor at this stage)

I know its asking a lot. So thank you in advance.

Any links of tuts would be appreciated as well.

**UPDATE**
I just relized that how google's search is working would be a perfect example. Autocomplete on the textbox & results start displaying as you type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your using jQuery and MVC3 the default MVC3 template aslo contains jQuery UI with has an autocomplete widget that is easily adaptable to what your after.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: ive used the autocomplete component before (actually tweakid it a little to work like dropdown), but noo idea to modify it to achieve what i've asked in this question...

Comment: @Yenros using the appendTo option you can change where you want the autocomplete results to appear, instead of directly below your output box you can have them appear in your div and by overriding the _renderItem method you could add a custom class based on the data returned to add a color based on relevancy. See [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) for an example on overriding _renderItem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered usign jQuery UI Autocomplete?
It seems to be valid for all the points that you mentioned.

You can check it out here:
[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)